# UITableView Rendering Deleted Cells

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, ios11

I currently have an issue with the rendering of a UITableViews cells in a Xamarin iOS project using MvvmCross V4.4.

If the first cell of a table view is deleted, the cell for the deleted row is not disposed of. I can only recreate the issue in iOS 11+.

The image shows a UITableView setup with a data source containing 3 items.
[image]

The top cell is then selected, this causes a new view to be displayed from where the user can delete the cell.

When the cell is deleted the new view is dismissed and ReloadData() is invoked on the table view. When the table view is rendered the cell for the deleted row is rendered over the top of the new top cell.
[image]

I have checked the data source and it contains 2 items (Cell Row 2 and Cell Row 3)

This only happens if the top cell is deleted, any other cell and the table view behaves as expected.

Any help in resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

### Update

I can mitigate the issue by manually invoking RemoveFromSuperView() on each subview of the UITableView, before invoking ReloadData(). However, this seems wrong.

Is there a better solution?

Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't look like an issue with "disposal of the element" rather than a cell reuse (object polling) issue. Notice the missing "target" icon on the lower right corner of the "Cell Row 3" after removal of "Cell Row 1"? I also assume you probably have 2 UILabels for displaying the Date with 2 different colours (Gold/Black) and you show/hide accordingly?
 Can you share code so you can get a better answer?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The target icon is to identify the item that was last interacted with. Therefore, there is no target icon to be displayed (as the item was deleted). The display of the date is done with three labels. The text and text colour of the labels are changed as required, yellow if the date is today.

Comment: @iamlcarus, the cell displaying "Cell Row 1" is not being removed from the UITableView's SubViews. It is not returned from a call to GetOrCreateCellForUITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item) (this is an MvvmCross method), is only called twice (for the second image). The cell that is being obscure and the last cell are the only cells that are returned from GetOrCreateCellFor when ReloadData() is invoked.

Comment: thanks for clearing that it up , i've made a wrong observation then :)

Comment: @iamlcarus, thank you for helping. Hopefully the additional detail added because of your comment will be enough to aid in resolving the issue.